# Route is not working fine in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My url is http://www.abc.com/login

I have created route

**match "login" => "sessions#new"**

**This is working fine now what I want is**

My new-url is http://www.abc.com/login/hello

**sometime the hello will be used sometime not**

My url is http://www.abc.com/login

My new route is

**match "login/:id" => "sessions#new"**

**When I use hello then it works but when I don't use hello in the url it show me error**

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/login/hello"
```

Comment: Did you try to invert the 2 rules in your routes.rb, so it would be `match "login/:id" => "sessions#new"` then `match "login" => "sessions#new"`

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure that what you're trying to do is really the "good way" to do, but as you didn't really explain in detail what you're trying to achieve, I don't know much more ...

Comment: hello will be organization name . some user have organization some don't so I need this some will type organization name in url and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

"When I use hello then it works but when I don't use hello in the url it show me error"
"No route matches [GET] "/login/hello"

Adding those two up, you somewhere add "hello" in your controllers or views, otherwise Ruby wouldn't show an error having "hello" in it...